# What all should be included in a motivation letter for PhD in Geology?

Tags: phd, application

What all should be added in a motivation letter for a PhD in Geology?

Should I write about:

1. My M.Sc project?
2. My schooling?
3. My hobbies?
4. How I got interested in that particular topic?

What can I do if I don't have enough experience in that particular project?